# remove element from a multidimensional array using string index

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multidimensional array which are timestamps of school schedules. I want to remove the timestamps that doesn't have schedule in it, which does make sense.

Array:

```
$array = [
  "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1
  ],
  "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
    1 => 1
  ]
];
```

The code I'm trying (which doesn't work as expected). The goal of the code is to remove the array element with the index of **06:00 AM - 06:05 AM** from the multidimensional array.

```
$toBeRemoved = '06:00 AM - 06:05 AM';

array_walk_recursive($array,
function (&$item, $key, $v) {
  if ($item == $v) $item = ''; 
}, $toBeRemoved);

print_r($array);
```

Code Output:

As you can see in the output, it doesn't removed the array element with an index of **06:00 AM - 06:05 AM**

```
Array
(
    [06:00 AM - 06:05 AM] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [06:05 AM - 06:10 AM] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

Expected Output:

As you can see, the **06:00 AM - 06:05 AM** is now gone from the array.

```
Array
(
    [06:05 AM - 06:10 AM] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove an element from an associative array

```
$array = [
  "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1
  ],
  "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
    1 => 1
  ]
];

unset($array["06:00 AM - 06:05 AM"]);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
  "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1
  ],
  "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
    1 => 1
  ]
  ];

  $toBeRemoved = '06:00 AM - 06:05 AM';

  $arrayNew = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $toBeRemoved) {
      continue;
    }
    $arrayNew[$key] = $value;
  }

  var_dump($arrayNew);
```

Comment: Thanks @amamoslavida , but what if I will still use the same `$array` for another loop iteration, the only difference is, the data are now reduced.

Comment: in my opinion, you should keep time data in database as TIMESTAMP, check php time() function, and better aproach is to use a database class which is written in PDO or use database classes of frameworks, such as codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

`array_walk_recursive` Keys having sub array will not passed to this recursive function.

[recursive doc.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

output:

```
a holds apple
b holds banana
sour holds lemon
```

You may notice that the key 'sweet' is never displayed. Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.

you may use following code snip

```
<?php
$result = [
  "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1
  ],
  "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
    1 => 1
  ]
];

$toBeRemoved = '06:00 AM - 06:05 AM';

foreach($result as $key => $value){
    if($key == $toBeRemoved ){
        unset($result[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shahzad Manzoor , let me try this one.

Comment: You explained it well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$array = [
    "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
        0 => 1
    ],
    "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
        1 => 1
    ]
];
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $val) {
        $new_array[] = $val;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```